# uploadprogress_get_info installed correctly and but not working in different code

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I know I have no issues with installing uploadprogress extension because when I tried this very simple tutorial: http://www.ultramegatech.com/2010/10/create-an-upload-progress-bar-with-php-and-jquery/, it worked beautifully!

I then tweaked it just a little bit to have a very simple (not jQuery-UI) progress bar, which also worked. Here's the working code:

upload_getprogress.php:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {
        $status = uploadprogress_get_info($_GET['uid']);
        if ($status) {
            echo round($status['bytes_uploaded']/$status['bytes_total']*100); 
        }
        else {
            echo 100; 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

upload_form.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Upload Something</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            #progress-bar, #upload-frame {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script>
           (function ($) { 
                var pbar;
                var started = false;

                $(function () {
                     $('#upload-form').submit(function() {
                        $('#upload-form').hide();
                        pbar = $('#progress-bar');
                        pbar.show();
                        $('#upload-frame').load(function () {
                            started = true;
                        });

                        setTimeout(function () { 
                            updateProgress($('#uid').val());
                        }, 1000); 
                    });
                });

                function updateProgress(id) {
                    var time = new Date().getTime();
                    $.get('upload_getprogress.php', { uid: id, t: time }, function (data) {
                        var progress = parseInt(data, 10);
                        if (progress < 100 || !started) {
                            started = progress < 100;
                            updateProgress(id);
                        }
                        started && $('#inner').css('width', progress+ "%"); 
                    });
                }
            }(jQuery));
        </script>
        <style>
        #progress-bar
        {
        height:50px;
        width:500px;
        border:2px solid black;
        background-color:white;
        margin:20px;
        }
        #inner
        {
        height:100%;
        background-color:orange;
        width:0%;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="upload-form"
              method="post"
              action="upload.php"
              enctype="multipart/form-data"
              target="upload-frame" >
            <input type="hidden"
                   id="uid"
                   name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER"
                   value="<?php echo $uid; ?>" >
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload!">
        </form>
        <div id="progress-bar"><div id='inner'></div>
        <iframe id="upload-frame" name="upload-frame"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

All fine and dandy, no issues! So I know for a fact there is nothing wrong with the way I've set up the `uploadprogress` extension.

However, having completed the demo successfully, I needed to integrate it into my javascript and jQuery intensive web-app, which includes file uploads.

Now when I try it, I get “NULL” from the uploadprogress_get_info() function. Why?
In my application page, my image upload form is created *dynamically*. But at the beginning of my page (and before the user hits a button that dynamically creates an image upload form), I am using this line:

```
<input type='hidden' name='UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER' id='uid' value='<?php echo md5(uniqid(mt_rand())); ?>' />
```

Is this the problem? Is there a specific time or place this hidden input should be present?

Before including the above line at the top of my page, I've also included a long .js file that includes a bunch of jQuery plugins, but starts with the following code:

```
            var started = false;

            function updateProgress(id) {
            console.log("updating progress"); // this msg appears, so i know i'm getting this far
                var time = new Date().getTime();

                $.get('upload_getprogress.php', { uid: id, t: time }, function (data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data, 10);

                    if (progress < 100 || !started) {
                        started = progress < 100;
                        updateProgress(id);

                    }
                     //started && pbar.progressbar('value', progress);
                   $('#inner').css('width', progress+ "%");

                });

            }

           // a lot more functions, then:
          function imageDialog(imgtype, x, y, editsource) {
          // this function dynamically generates a dialog for image uploading
          // which shows up when a user hits an "image upload" button
          // there's lots of code that creates a new form which is assigned to $imgform
          // lots of elements and a couple of iframes are appended to $imgform 
          // then finally: 

             $imgform.submit(function() {
        pbar = $('#progress-bar');
        $('#inner').css('width', "0%");
        pbar.show();
        started = true;
        setTimeout(function () {
                        updateProgress($('#uid').val()); 
                    }, 1000);
    });

         /* other irrelevant stuff */

          }
```

However, while the upload progress bar shows up as expected, it never increases in progress.

So I edited the upload_getprogress.php to look like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['uid'])) {
    $uid = $_GET['uid'];
        //$status = uploadprogress_get_info($_GET['uid']);
    echo "progress for $uid is: ".uploadprogress_get_info($uid);
 }
```

In Firefox, I can see the response of the ajax call, and what I get as output from upload_getprogress.php is:

```
progress for 6e728b67bd526bceb077c02231d2ec6f is:
```

I tried to dump `$status` into a variable and output to file, and the file said:

```
the current uid: 02e9a3e0214ffd731265ec5b0b220b4c
the current status: NULL
```

So basically, the status is consistently returning `NULL`. Why? This was (and still is) working fine in the demo, what could be going wrong while integrating it into my web app code? There's nothing wrong with the image uploading on its own - my images are getting uploaded fine, but the progress isn't getting tracked!

The form that gets created dynamically looks like this:

```
<div class="dialog-container">
<form id="imgform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload_1-img.php" target="upload_target">
Select image:
<br>
<input id="image" type="file" name="image">
<div id="imgwrapper"></div>
<input id="filename" type="hidden" value="" name="filename">
<input id="upath" type="hidden" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" name="upath">
<center>
<input id="imgupload" type="submit" onclick="showUploadedItem()" value="Upload">
<input id="clearcrop" type="button" disabled="disabled/" value="Clear selection">
<input id="imgapproved" type="button" disabled="disabled" value="Done">
<input id="imgcancel" type="button" value="Cancel">
</center>
</form>
</div>
<div id="progress-bar"><div id='inner'></div></div>
<!-- etc etc some other elements -->
</div>
```

and my own upload_1-img.php starts off with:

```
    $filename = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"];       
    $file_info = new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME);
    $bfr = $file_info->buffer(file_get_contents($filename)) or die ("error");
    // some more stuff, getting file type and file's $name
    if( /* a bunch of conditions */ )
        move_uploaded_file( $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $upath . "/" . $name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Woohoo! I figured it out, thanks to this bug:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=57505

Basically, just I removed this static line from the page where users get to upload files:

```
<input type='hidden' name='UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER' id='uid' value='<?php echo md5(uniqid(mt_rand())); ?>' />
```

and in my javascript function that creates the image dialog dynamically, I just added the hidden input dynamically, right above the line where I generated the file input.

So the relevant part of the dynamically created form then looks like:

```
<input type='hidden' name='UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER' id='uid' value='1325a38f3355c0b1b4' />
<input id="image" type="file" name="image">
```

Now since this is getting dynamically created via javascript anyway, I can just replace that value above with a random js function.

Now the progress bar is advancing as it ought to! :D